# Issue with waitforimages plugin

Tags: jquery, waitforimages

A DragandDrop website builder (weebly) I'm using is using the waitforimages plugin:

https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages

The background image on the homepage of my site only loads intermittently (and rarely).

I found an uncaught type error `waitforimages is not a function` related to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.top-background-image').css('display', 'none')
  $('.top-background-image').waitForImages({
    finished: function() {      
        $(this).fadeIn(2000);           
    }   
  }); 
});
```

I'm out of my depth so any thoughts on the source of the issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please don't include the source code of the `waitforimage`-library, but include the relevate source code from your homepage. At least, a `;` is missing in your code.